# Maintain dask dataframe index between .values and .to_dask_dataframe

Tags: dask

I'm using a library that takes in a Dask Dataframe and basically does `return ddf.map_partitions(...).values` ([lightgbm](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/blob/894066dbcd7a912da13dd4243ad74b7d992f3d93/python-package/lightgbm/dask.py#L956)).

I've set an index on my input DataFrame and want to join my results back onto my input features for further processing. If the library function returned `ddf.map_partitions()` it'd be a simple `join`. Since it instead returns an array, I find myself doing `arr.to_dask_dataframe(index=ddf.index).join(ddf)`.

My question is basically: is this safe? What guarantees that the same chunks of the index will be assigned to the corresponding chunks in the output? I.e. what makes that I don't end up with:
[Shuffled index after assign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN4yu.png)